# Rspec - access describe name in describe context, not in `it`

Tags: ruby, rspec, describe

I have such simplifyed rspec code:

```
require 'rspec'

describe 'DescribeTitle' do
  describe_name = self.class.description
  p describe_name
  it 'should do something' do
    expect(true).to be_truthy
  end
end
```

I want to access 'DescribeTitle' befor entering to `it`.

I found out I can use `self.class.description` to get it, but seems it works only inside `it`'s.

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case

```
self.class
#=> Class
```

Thus, because you are in the context of the `DescribeTitle` already, you need to just use `self.description` instead of `self.class.description`:

```
self.description
#=> DescribeTitle
```

Comment: @ShockwaveNN What you *always* want to know is the value of `self`. Once you understand it, half of your questions are gone :)